# Swift Protocol for present() function in UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'd like to create a protocol (delegate) which the current UIViewController.present funcion conforms to.

so for example the protocol is:

```
protocol PresentPopupDelegate
{
     func doSomething()
     func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Swift.Void)?)
}
```

The class that needs to conform to this protocol is :

```
class MyViewController:UIViewController, PresentPopupDelegate {

       func doSomething()
}
```

and lets say I have this code :

```
let delegate:PresentPopupDelegate

init() {
    self.delegate = MyViewController()
}
```

compiling this will result in a warning saying

> Method 'present:animated:completion:' in protocol 'PresentPopupDelegate' not implemented

Now i'm assuming that the the reason is because in the original function has a default parameter set to the completion function as "nil".
However, Protocols do not support default params.

So to my question: Can I, and if so how, create a protocol in which the UIViewController.present(...) function can conform to ?

Answer (score 3):

Types do not conform to protocols just because they have the right functions in them. You have to explicitly say that the type conforms. In your case, that just means adding:

```
extension UIViewController: PresentPopupDelegate {}
```

There's no need for a body here, since it already has the right implementations.

This choice to require explicit conformance was an intentional design decision in Swift. See Ole Begemann's excellent summary of the reasoning in [Protocols are more than Bags of Syntax](https://oleb.net/blog/2016/12/protocols-have-semantics/).

Comment: Good call. And a great read !!!, I've added the extension to UIViewController. But am now getting the following error :
method 'presentViewController:animated:completion:' provided by method 'present(_:animated:completion:)' does not match the requirement's selector ('present:animated:completion:')

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Are you sure your protocol is exactly what you listed here? In particular, are you sure you're not missing the `_` before the first parameter?

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect better what I'm trying to do. 
To your q: the _ is not missing from the func.
Thanks!

Comment: I still can't reproduce this. I put your code into a playground and it compiles without error.